# Where do I store Google Cloud service account key file?

Tags: heroku, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-storage

I have a DRF app that i am deploying to Heroku. I am integrating Google Cloud Storage in my app and have downloaded the service account key file and set it as an environment variable in my macOS and also in my Heroku config vars. The file is located in the documents folder of my OS. when i run app locally it works but when i deploy to Heroku i get error saying it can't find the file or directory. Where do i securely store these credentials?

The way I call for the file in my django settings: `GCS_CREDENTIALS = os.environ.get("GCS_CREDENTIALS")`

Comment: https://docs.keeper.io/secrets-manager/secrets-manager/integrations/heroku